# Open a new page in Chrome extension windows using <a> tag

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension which there is a link on the default HTML page. When I click my extension and I click on hyperlink nothing happens.

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_self">Log In</a>
```

I searched the `stackoverflow` but many suggested using `target="_blank"`. The problem is I don't want to open it in a new tab or window. I want to see it in my extension popup. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You'll have to use an iframe.

Comment: @wOxxOm May I ask respectfully for the reason why above method is not working?

Comment: Because redirecting the popup to a web URL is no longer allowed.

Comment: I want to add login with Oauth to my extension that's why it redirects to the log in page but when I use I frame I get an error which says: ``You are not authorized to view this page`` and issues such as: ``Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in a cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute``
I don't get these error when use normal tab to login